# Firebase Friendlychat https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat chat notification issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have cloned and ran the github https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat friendly chat project for Android. It is creating chat app between all users but I was expecting to see a notification since they have included FirebaseMessagingService in the code.

AM I expecting to much or I need to change something in code to get notification in my notification bar?

Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: I think you should look for any similar issue on there repo, if not you should file one!

Comment: Notifications are managed from Firebase Console, not from application, check second part of this course: https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was way off in my question.
So, in order to have one on one notification I had to create php files in my own server. My server code will have FCM key from firebase and when user sends a message, I send a push request from my application to server including receiver's FCM token, it will send a notification to Firebase and Firebase will send notification to the receiver.

Google have firebase functions and somehow you don't need your own server anymore but I am not sure how to implement that.